# Sending .csv files to a database: MariaDB

Tags: json, database, raspberry-pi, mariadb, sensors

I will preface this by saying I am very new to databases. I am working on a project for my undergraduate research that requires various sensor data to be send from a Raspberry Pi via the internet to a database. I am using MariaDB at the moment, but am open to other options.

The background: Currently all sensor data is being saved in csv files on the RPi. There will be automation to send data at given intervals to the database.

The question: Am I able to audit the file itself to a database? For our application, a csv file is the most logical data storage format and we simply want the database to be a way for us to retrieve data remotely, since the system will be installed miles away from where we work.

I have read about "LOAD DATA INFILE" on this website, but am unsure how it applies to this database. Would JSON be at all applicable for this? I am willing to learn if it makes the process more streamlined.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'sending data to the database' means that, by one means or another, additional or replacement CSV files are saved on disk, in a location accessible to a MariaDB client program, then you can load these into the database using the "mysql" command-line client and an appropriate script of SQL commands.  That script very likely will make use of the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command.

The "mysql" program may be launched in a variety of ways: 1) spawned by the process that receives the uploaded file; 2) launched by a cron job (Task Scheduler on Windows) that runs periodically to check for new or changed CSV files; of 3) launched by a daemon that continually monitors the disk for new or changed CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV is typically human readable. I would work with that first before worrying about using JSON. Unless the CSVs are huge, you could probably open them up in a simple text editor to read their contents to get an idea of what the data looks like.

I'm not sure of your environment (feel free to elaborate), but you could just use whatever web services you have to read in the CSV directly and inject the data into your database.

You say that data is being sent using automation. How is it communicating to your web service?

What is your web service? (Is it php?)

Where is the database being hosted? (Is it in the same webservice?)